# Regex negation operator works differently in java versions

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

i ran into a regex negation operator problem with carriage return durnig code migration from java 8 to 11.
Simplyfied problem: there is a tag regex pattern:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<(\\w+)>([^<]*?)</\\1>", Pattern.CANON_EQ);  // pattern for "<tag>...</tag>"
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("<a>bla\\r\\nbla</a>");
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
...
}
```

It works in java 8. (It finds patterns in input.)

In java 11 it doesnt. Only if i remove flag Pattern.CANON_EQ, or modify regex to positive pattern, e.g:

```
"<(\\w+)>(.*?)</\\1>" with Pattern.DOTALL
```

The critical part is "\r" in the input. It causes the problem: if it isnt in the input, it works in java 11 as well.

Why?

Comment: Works in Java 14 though...

Comment: It worked for me on Java 11 as well

Comment: What if you use `Pattern.DOTALL` but still use the negative character class?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin `DOTALL` won't change anything, since there is no `.` (dot) in the regex.

Comment: @Andreas, it might be implied by a negative character class.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin No, a negative character class is not a "dot", only `.` is a "dot".

Comment: @Andreas, some version of Java *might* treat a negative character class as dot minus some characers, thus making `Pattern.DOTALL` relevant. It may be worth checking.

Comment: Seems to work in Java 11: https://onecompiler.com/java/3w9mntts7.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin If "some version of Java" did that, that version of the Java Runtime Library would be in violation of the contract defined for `Pattern`, since the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt) only specifies special line terminator handling for `.`, not for negative character classes.